# Ask different response from servlet and use AJAX and JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I'm new at this, I mean using JSP, servlet and JavaScript/jQuery/AJAX. I want to make the drop-down menu comes from new response depend on the request. But, it seems that I could not find a way to make the servlet send different response.
I want to use AJAX in order to avoid page reload, so the specific drop-down element that will be reloaded.
I'd made the service for the server side. The code I put here is the one in client side. In client side we use JSP, Servlet, and JavaScript/jQuery.

**Here's my JSP:**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Coba aja</title>
        <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/basic.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <select name="idprovinsi" id="idprovinsi">
            <option value="" >--Pilih Provinsi--</option>
        </select>

        <select name="idkota" id="idkota">
            <option value="" >--Pilih Kota/Kabupaten--</option>
        </select>

        <select name="idkecamatan" id="idkecamatan">
            <option value="" >--Pilih Kecamatan--</option>
        </select>

        <select name="iddesa" id="iddesa">
            <option value="" >--Pilih Desa--</option>
        </select>

        <input type="hidden" id="dropdown" value="">
    </body>
</html>
```

**Here's my JavaScript:**

```
var arrayProvinsi = new Array();
var arrayKota = new Array();
var arrayKecamatan = new Array();
var arrayDesa = new Array();

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#idkota').hide();
$('#idkecamatan').hide();
$('#iddesa').hide();
//alert("load pertama kali!");


    $('#idprovinsi').ready(function(){
        //alert("masuk ready!");
       $.ajax({
           url:"../update",
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(msg){
                //alert(msg);
                //alert(msg.length);

                var temp = new Array();
                temp = msg.arrayProvinsi;

                //alert(temp);
                //alert(temp.length);

                var selObj = document.getElementById("idprovinsi");

                for (var i=0; i < temp.length;++i)
                {
                    //alert("nama:"+msg[i].provinsiname);
                    addOptionProvinsi(selObj, temp[i].provinsiname, temp[i].idprovinsi);
                }
            }
       });
    });

    $('#idprovinsi').change(function(){
        //alert($('#idprovinsi').val());        
        $('#idkota').show();
        $('#dropdown').val("kota");
        alert("dropdown provinsi change alert! nilai id provinsi: "+$('#idprovinsi').val()+" nilai dropdown:"+$('#dropdown').val());

         $.ajax({
           url:"../update",
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(msg){
                alert(msg.length);
                var temp = new Array();
                temp = msg.arrayKota;
                alert(temp.length);
                var selObj = document.getElementById("idkota");
                for (var i=0; i < msg.length;++i)
                {
                    alert("nama:"+temp[i].kotaname);
                    addOptionKota(selObj, msg[i].kotaname, msg[i].idkota);
                }
            }
       });
    });

});

function addOptionProvinsi(selectbox,text,value )
{
    if(isInArray(text, arrayProvinsi)){

    }else{
        arrayProvinsi.push(text);
        var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
        optn.text = text;
        optn.value = value;
        selectbox.options.add(optn);
    }

}

function addOptionKota(selectbox,text,value )
{
    if(isInArray(text, arrayKota)){

    }else{
        arrayKota.push(text);
        var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
        optn.text = text;
        optn.value = value;
        selectbox.options.add(optn);
    }

}

function isInArray(value, array) {
  return array.indexOf(value) > -1 ? true : false;
}
```

**Here's my servlet:**

```
@WebServlet("/update")
public class CobaServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    } 

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        Map <String,Object> map= new HashMap<String, Object>();
        //get data All Provinsi
        String url="";
    CallService cs= new CallService();
    String feedback ="";
        MultivaluedMapImpl  params = new MultivaluedMapImpl();

        String dropdown     = request.getParameter("dropdown");

        String idprovinsi   = request.getParameter("idprovinsi");
        String idkota       = request.getParameter("idkota");
        String idkecamatan  = request.getParameter("idkecamatan");
        String iddesa       = request.getParameter("iddesa");


        if(idprovinsi != null && !idprovinsi.equals("")){
            //get data All Kota
            url = "http://localhost:8080/sPuskesmas/rest/kotaservice/getKotaByIdprovinsi";
            params.add("idprovinsi", idprovinsi);
            feedback = cs.callGetService(url,params);
            JSONArray arrayKota= JsonToArray.toArray(feedback);

            //write(response, arrayKota);
            //request.setAttribute("arrayKota", arrayKota);
            map.put("arrayKota", arrayKota);
            write(response,map);
         }
        else if(idprovinsi==null || idprovinsi.equals("")){
            url = "http://localhost:8080/sPuskesmas/rest/provinsiservice/getAllProvinsi";
            feedback = cs.callGetService(url);
            JSONArray arrayProvinsi= JsonToArray.toArray(feedback);

            //write(response, arrayProvinsi);
            //request.setAttribute("arrayProvinsi", arrayProvinsi);
            map.put("arrayProvinsi", arrayProvinsi);
            write(response,map);

        }
    }

    private void write(HttpServletResponse response, Map<String, Object> map) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(map));
    }

    private void write(HttpServletResponse response, JSONArray arrayNya) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(arrayNya));
    }

}
```

I don't know how I can get different response, because I always get the same first response. ***I just want to access different part of the servlet so I can get the response I want***. Can you help me solve it?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is pass one parameter to servlet  like

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'servletname?&selecttype=idprovinsi', //change this for each combo
          success:function(data){

          }
        });
```

in servlet

```
    String type= req.getParameter("selecttype");

    if(type.equals("idprovinsi")){
   --dosomething
   }
```

handle that parameter in servlet and make difference in your response.

Accoring to that fill the combo in success.

Comment: I had done as you suggested, but it turn out to be error--> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error). So, is "selecttype" in javascript can be access from servlet just like that? or should I do something using hidden input type in jsp?

Comment: What you see in servlet debug,is that param value coming there ??

Comment: btw, when I change the order of "if conditions", the error disappear. But, I still get the "arrayProvinsi" result only. I need the "arrayKota". Even though the url had already changed into url:"../update?&selecttype=idprovinsi", in chrome console it appear as it is. But the condition if in servlet seems doesn't work.

Comment: @SURESH ATTA The truth is when I run the jsp page, I have no idea where I can see the value in the servlet. Which panel should I check in order to see the param value. Can you tell me how? Thanks